# Nested for loop parallization with CUDA with an "IF" condition

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I need to convert following sample nested for loop with an IF condition. My problem is how to use/ pass 'count' value in parallel kernels.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N-1 ; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
    {
         //function and result is t
         if (t <5.0)
         {   1D_vector_1 [count] = i;
             1D_vector_2 [count] = j;
             count= count + 1;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can atomically increment `count` as per the linked duplicate. Note that it will not be very fast. If the number of times you increment `count`  is very large, you should consider  using another algorithm, like writing into a thread specific position conditionally, and use stream compaction to strip the empty entries afterwards

Comment: could anyone give pseudocode for this sample?